# Listing images in pop up button

Tags: cocoa

How can i display a list of images stored in an array as list item in pop up button.

If not possible, what can be the alternative way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSMenuItem has a -setImage: method which allows you to assign a image to be displayed with the menu item in a popup button.

NSMenu has a number of methods which allow you to obtain the NSMenuItem's from it, like -itemWithTag:, itemWithTitle:, etc.

Furthermore, NSPopupButton has a number of methods which allow you to obtain the NSMenuItem's from it like, -itemArray, -itemAtIndex:, etc. and, of course, a -menu method which allows you to obtain its NSMenu directly.

Comment: is it that i have to add image objects in menu and add that menu to popupbutton to display.

Comment: No, you should simply need to grab the NSMenuItem's from the button and use the -setImage: method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the user chose an image from a selection, you should consider ImageKit and its [`IKImageBrowserView`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not my requirement.